# Divider in RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, divider

I have DrawerNavigation, it is RecyclerView cues of 14 elements. And I need to divide the elements of the list by using the divider, but I do not need to do so with every element of the list. For example, I need to set a divider after 2 and 5 of the list item. I found just how to make dividers for the entire list, but when I use `drawerList.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration, 2);` So It return an error.
This is Main Class:

```
drawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new DrawerListItemAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,getResources().getString(R.string.nickname),
            getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_second_line),PROFILE, this);       // Creating the Adapter of DrawerListItemAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
    // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
    // and header view profile picture
    drawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager
    drawerList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    drawerListClick(drawerList, this, toolbar, nameProfile);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
            // open I am not going to put anything here)
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
        }
    }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new
            DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST);
    Log.d("SIZE OF LIST", "Size " + drawerList.getAdapter().getItemCount());
    drawerList.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

This work fine, but it's work for all item's of list 
This is adapter of drawerList:

```
public class DrawerListItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerListItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;  // Declaring Variable to Understand which View is being worked on
// IF the view under inflation and population is header or Item
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles Value from MainActivity.java
private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons resource value from MainActivity.java
private String name;        //String Resource for header View Name
private int profile;        //int Resource for header view profile picture
private String email;       //String Resource for header view email
private BaseActivity context;


// Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
// ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to recycle them

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    int Holderid;

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView profile;
    ImageView dad;
    ImageView mam;
    TextView Name;
    TextView email;
    RelativeLayout layout;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView,int ViewType) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
        super(itemView);
        // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created
        if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
            Holderid = 1;                                               // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row
            layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
        }
        else{
            Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
            profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);// Creating Image view object from header.xml for profile pic
            Holderid = 0;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
            dad = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleViewDad);
            mam = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleViewMam);
        }
    }


}

public DrawerListItemAdapter(String Titles[], int Icons[], String Name, String Email, int Profile, BaseActivity context){ // DrawerListItemAdapter Constructor with titles and icons parameter
    // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the main activity as we
    mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
    mIcons = Icons;
    name = Name;
    email = Email;
    profile = Profile;                     //here we assign those passed values to the values we declared here
    //in adapter
    this.context = context;
}



//Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when the ViewHolder is
//Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
// if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
// and pass it to the view holder

@Override
public DrawerListItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false); //Inflating the layout
        ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view
        return vhItem; // Returning the created object
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header,parent,false); //Inflating the layout
        ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v,viewType); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view
        return vhHeader; //returning the object created
    }
    return null;
}
//Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is needed to be displayed, here the int position
// Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed and the holder id of the holder object tell us
// which view type is being created 1 for item row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DrawerListItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
        // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
        holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position - 1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons
    }
    else{

        holder.profile.setImageResource(profile);           // Similarly we set the resources for header view
        holder.profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Bundle bndl = new Bundle();
                //bndl.putInt("ToolbarHeight", toolbar.getLayoutParams().height);
                //ProfileFragment eventsViewPagerFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                //FragmentTransaction transaction = context.getSupportFragmentManager()
                //        .beginTransaction();
                //eventsViewPagerFragment.setArguments(bndl);
                //transaction.replace(R.id.general_fragment, eventsViewPagerFragment);
                //toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                //transaction.commit();
                Intent in = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("Image", 0);
                context.startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        holder.dad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("Image", 2);
                context.startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        holder.mam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("Image", 1);
                context.startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        holder.Name.setText(name);
        holder.email.setText(email);
    }
}
// This method returns the number of items present in the list
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNavTitles.length+1; // the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
}

// Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}
private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}
}
```

And this class for divider:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};

public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;
public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;
private Drawable mDivider;
private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, int itemPosition, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}
```

}

My question is how to make the divider between certain elements of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of this library https://github.com/yqritc/RecyclerView-FlexibleDivider to get the desired effect.

The function that actually gonna help you in hiding divider is the following

```
 @Override
public boolean shouldHideDivider(int position, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (position == 14 || position == 15) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you go through the ComplexActivity and ComplexAdapter class in the sample, you will get to know how to actually make use of this function.

Comment: You should share some code and explanation for a better answer quality. Because when the link is no more available the answer will not make a sense anymore.

Comment: @DhiaTN I understand your point but the user needs to add that library dependency to his  project, so link is anyway required to be put in the answer, so that anyone who's looking for this solution can go through the sample program.